Add Salesforce Data Cloud data in Bigquery in Python
I am trying to add Salesforce Data Cloud data in BigQuery. I am able to add the source through console as shown in the picture:
.
I was wondering if this can be done programmatically through Terraform or Python.

When I tried to examine in the console, I got no listings ... but instead "If you are a Salesforce Data Cloud customer and have no access or shares are not visible, please contact your Salesforce Data Cloud admin.".  It feels like this is an access share through Analytics Hub.  If yes, then there are APIs that can be used to perform the associated actions .... https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/analytics-hub/rest ...

I have access to view the shares. For Salesforce Data Cloud listings, there is a button in the Explorer pane that automatically filters related listings. Read point 3 in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/analytics-hub-view-subscribe-listings#discover-listings. I want to create a linked dataset based on the listings programmatically.

It appears that the solution to our puzzle lies in the use of Google Analytics Hub.  It appears that the data you seek is exposed through that service.  If correct, then the question subtly changes to "How do I interact with Google Analytics Hub in a programatic fashion".  To create a subscription (create a link to a dataset), this appears to be the API we would want to use.  There should be language bindings beyond the raw REST request.   You mentioned Python, here are the docs for the Python bindings.
Let me suggest that you review those docs and associated programming guides for interacting with Analytics Hub.  There appears to be a rich set of samples here.  If after studying you run into new puzzles that can't be solved by research, post a new question and we'll jump in.
